# 2 google developer console account with different email address on a laptop

Tags: android, developer-console

I already have 1 google developer console account on my laptop and I need to buy a new google developer console to a specific app.

is that safe if I create 2 google developer console account with different email addresses on 1 laptop?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [SO Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55291/google-play-developer-console-switch-between-accounts) suggests using different browsers as the accounts are tracked with cookies.